Javascript Loop repeats within the same tag instead of attaching <br>
I am trying to create a simple math table of 2 printed out in a  tag, below is my HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Table of 2</h1>
    <p id="table-goes-here">Goes here</p>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

and below is the JS I wrote:
let userNumber = 2;
let tableRow = document.getElementById("table-goes-here");

for(counter = 1; counter <= 12; counter++) {
    tableRow.innerHTML = counter + " x " + userNumber + " = " + counter * userNumber + "<br>";
};

my desired output is:
**Table of 2**

1 x 2 = 2
2 x 2 = 4
3 x 2 = 6
4 x 2 = 8
5 x 2 = 10
6 x 2 = 12
7 x 2 = 14
8 x 2 = 16
9 x 2 = 18
10 x 2 = 20
11 x 2 = 22
12 x 2 = 24

In above output the heading would be  and the rest all of the table rows will be in a single  tag, but the output that I am getting is:
**Table of 2**

12 x 2 = 24

I am now thinking that my JS code is just repeating itself within the same line and that's why it's displaying just the last line of code, I have google a lot on this and also tried \n and \r solutions but nothing seems to be working I would really appreciate any help :)
with that said, I was able to get the desired output with:
let userNumber = 2;
let tableRow = document.getElementById("table-goes-here");

for(counter = 1; counter <= 12; counter++) {
    document.write(counter + " x " + userNumber + " = " + counter * userNumber + "<br>");
};

but obviously this way I wasn't able to place the dynamically generated content into the  tags.

try tableRow.innerHTML += - the way you do it, you replace the content in every iteration, rather than add to it

Oh yes, thanks @JaromandaX replacing "=" with "+=" worked like a charm :) really appreciate the help.

You should be using DOM methods such as createElement to create dynamic content. Avoid innerHTML and especially document.write.
